# Is that true, for selfadjoint endomorphisms that $ \alpha \ \circ \ \beta = \beta \ \circ\ \alpha $. Then is $\beta \ \circ\ \alpha$ selfadjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $V$ a finite-dimensional Euclidean vector space and $ \alpha, \beta: V \rightarrow V$ selfadjoint endomorphisms which commutate, which means that $ \alpha \ \circ \ \beta = \beta \ \circ\ \alpha $. Then is $\beta \ \circ\ \alpha$ selfadjoint .

I'm learning the spectral theorem and I found this problem which I can't solve.
As I know $\alpha $ and $ \beta$ are self-adjoint if and only if it is described by a Hermetian matrix with respect to one orthonormal basis of $V$. I'm still struggling how to show it that the exercise above is true or false. I would appreciate any kind of your help.

Comment: @H You're likely expected to use the fact that $(\alpha \circ \beta)^* = \beta^* \circ \alpha^*$.

Comment: does this property have a name?

Comment: I know that this is true for the transpose of the matrix multiplication

Comment: @H There is no official or even common name for this fact, as far as I know. It can be neatly summarized as an expression for the "adjoint of a composition", and Googling this phrase results in some hits. I would be very surprised if this fact did not appear in your textbook/notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\forall x,y\in V, \big\langle (\beta \circ \alpha)(x),y\big\rangle &= \big\langle (\alpha \circ \beta)(x),y\big\rangle = \Big\langle \alpha\big(\beta(x)\big),y\Big\rangle = \big\langle \beta(x),\alpha^* (y)\big\rangle = \big\langle \beta(x),\alpha (y)\big\rangle \\
&= \Big\langle x, \beta^* \big(\alpha (y)\big)\Big\rangle = \Big\langle x, \beta \big(\alpha (y)\big)\Big\rangle = \big\langle x,(\beta \circ \alpha)(y)\big\rangle
\end{align*}